# Delete lines containing words from a list of words

Tags: excel, bash, sed

How Can I delete lines that contain numbers from a list? bash or any other scripting language or excel or an application.

here is my example:

```
COLUMN A                COLUMN B
____________________________________________
192.168.1.1:27794           27800
192.168.1.1:27795           27799
192.168.1.1:27796           27794
192.168.1.1:27797           27795
192.168.1.1:27798
192.168.1.1:27799
192.168.1.1:27800
192.168.1.1:27801
```

Column A and column B are apart files.

Column A full.txt Column B todelfromfull.txt

so if the lines from column A contain words from column B I want the lines from column A to be deleted that are in column B

I tried something with sed in bash but without success

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk -F : 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($2 in a) ' todelfromfull.txt full.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `-F :` Field Split by `:`
- `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}` read the first file `todelfromfull.txt`, save the ports in associative array `a`
- `!($2 in a)` if column 2 is not in array a, print it.

Answer (score 2):

Use GNU grep:

```
fgrep -vw -f todelfromfull.txt full.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Bash:

```
file=$(< todelfromfull.txt)
while IFS=: read ip port; do
    n=0
    for i in $file; do
        if [[ $i == $port ]]; then
            ((n++))
            break
        fi
    done
    if [ $n -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $ip $port
    fi
done < full.txt
```